# Alternative for django.db.close_connection()

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-database

Is there a possible way to re-establish MySQL connection in Django after it goes down?

I am getting the following error while trying to access MySQL using the `get_wsgi_application` in `django.core.wsgi`:

```
(2006,'MYSQL server has gone away')
```

Answer (score 4):

We need to close the old connection to db, which Django had automatically created before.

We can do this by executing the function:

```
django.db.close_old_connections()
```

Django automatically creates new connections after closing previous connections.